# MS Access - What's wrong with this DCount statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access, record-count

I'm getting an error with the following line of code:

```
DCount("Letter Status","Letter Status","[Letter Status] = 'Received letter'")
```

The error I'm getting in Access 2007 says

> Missing Operator but I don't see how or where.

(Letter status is the name of the field and the table (it's a working design, sorry)

Comment: Is that error message verbatim? ;)

Comment: Don't wait until production: lose the spaces in the data element names (hence the square brackets) *now*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing some square brackets:

```
 DCount("[Letter Status]","[Letter Status]","[Letter Status] = 'Received letter'")
```

It is best to name fields and tables without using spaces.

Comment: I'll go further: NEVER, **EVER** create your database objects with spaces in the names. Or use reserved words to name your objects. Just because Access lets you commit these sins doesn't mean that you should.